# How to mention someone who is mentioned in a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Actually, I'm trying to make a command, where the bot mentions the person who is mentioned in the command (if the command is "!kill @otherperson", then the bot says "@otherperson is dead now.")
So kindly help with the same, I don't have any code at the moment, because I don't really have any idea what's going on here.

Comment: How do you normally make a command? Think of that first. Then how do you use a Member argument?

Comment: _... I don't have any code at the moment,..._ That is bad. We expect you to show some code and ask a specific question "about the code" in order to help you finding your issues.

Comment: oh sorry for these mistakes, I'm actually new to stackoverflow, I will surely take care of these next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mentions field on a Message object to get a list users mentioned as Member objects and then use the mention field on those to get a string which mentions the user.

Sample code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def kill(ctx, arg):
    users = ctx.message.mentions
    if len(users) > 0:
        await ctx.send(f'{users[0].mention} is dead now.')
```

Comment: I know you want to help. But we don't write code from scratch.

Comment: Oh my god it worked like a charm